# BitBlt failing on window rendered by OpenGL

Tags: c#, winapi, opengl, bitmap

I'm making a program to take a screenshot of a game while I'm streaming, so it take a screenshot and save it automatically, but when I set the game to use OpenGL my function fail, it keep saving the same image over and over again, it just change the image after I restart the game.

It seems it works in the first run, but on the next ones it keep saving the first image.

Here is what I'm using:

```
public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd) {
       try {
           RECT rc;
           GetClientRect(hwnd, out rc);

           IntPtr hdcFrom = GetDC(hwnd);
           IntPtr hdcTo = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcFrom);
           //X and Y coordinates of window
           int Width = rc.right;
           int Height = rc.bottom;
           Bitmap bmp = null;

           IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcFrom, Width, Height);
           if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero) {
               // adjust and copy
               IntPtr hLocalBitmap = SelectObject(hdcTo, hBitmap);

               BitBlt(hdcTo, 0, 0, Width, Height, hdcFrom, 0, 0, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
               SelectObject(hdcTo, hLocalBitmap);
               //We delete the memory device context.
               DeleteDC(hdcTo);
               //We release the screen device context.
               ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcFrom);
               //Image is created by Image bitmap handle and assigned to Bitmap variable.
               bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
               //Delete the compatible bitmap object. 
               DeleteObject(hBitmap);
               bmp.Save("saving.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
           }

           return bmp;
       }
       catch {

       }

       return new Bitmap(0, 0);
   }
```

If I change the game graphic to use DirectX it works good, it's just happening while using OpenGL, so not sude if it must be different for openGL windows or if it's impossible to capture those kind of window.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the old bitmap from the first run before trying to save a bmp a 2nd time with the same file name?

Comment: Yes, actually I made it check files with the same name to add a number in the end, so it could save, "saving1", "saving2" etc, still the same behavior.

Comment: It works with DirectX because of [DXGI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404534.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Using double buffered OpenGL is mutually exclusive with using GDI operations¹. Use `glReadPixels` to take a screenshot.

---

¹: Well, technically if you know what you're doing and take the right precautions you can mix them. But it's more trouble than it's worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

After a recent windows 10 update, DirectX rendered windows now suffer from the same problem.  I found a workaround, but you're not going to like it...
If you set hwnd = 0, the BitBlt now refers to the whole screen, instead of just one window.  Then you can change BitBlt's source offset values to grab only the target window.
Although this works, its much slower than the original way you had it.  :(
On my laptop, grabbing a 1080p window used to take 3ms, but now, using this workaround, it takes 27ms, which really ruins the streaming performance.  :(
Still, its better than nothing.